# Export exposed fields into a block with Views

Tags: blocks, search, views

I'm trying to create a **search box from the exposed fields** from a view. Is that possible? If I add a block display I also get the results.. I want only the fields, not both.

I also tried embedding a view with exposed filters inside a node, however, when I click "search" I'm not redirected to the view (the url is not constructed correctly: instead of website.com/**view**?exposed_field=test I get website.com/?exposed_field=test).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://www.timonweb.com/how-display-views-exposed-filter-block-and-theme-it -- it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is now built into Views itself.  See [How To Display Views' Exposed Filter In A Block And Theme It](http://timonweb.com/how-display-views-exposed-filter-block-and-theme-it) for details.